# Tarantool readahead limit is reached warning

Tags: lua, tarantool

Why there are too much warnings in logs (`tarantool-1.10.3-0-g0b7078a`):

> readahead limit is reached

How to eliminate them?

Answer (score 3):

Generally that means that there are more incoming requests to Tarantool than it can handle (so they are throttled). If you see this occasionally - it's ok, it is related to workload spikes. If you see them constantly - you should explore your workload more thoroughly and, depending on results:

1. adjust readahead parameter
   https://www.tarantool.io/en/doc/1.10/reference/configuration/#cfg-networking-readahead
2. adjust net_msg_max parameter
   https://www.tarantool.io/en/doc/1.10/reference/configuration/#cfg-networking-net-msg-max
3. optimize your application code
4. think about scaling out to handle workload (replication, sharding)

Comment: As I understood, `net_msg_max` is a number of fibers for consiming the queue and processing requests. Is there any limits for the value?